# Iphone news reader

Tags: ios

I want to develop news reader program based on ios sdk.
So I searched many sites and spots to find the similary program,
but I couldn't find this.
Every application requires costs and though they don't publish their source code.
I hope your help even though you describes code partly.
Hope for your help.

Comment: What is your question? Do want good links for creating an iPhone News Reader?

Comment: From where do you want to read news?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the feed using a `NSUrlConnection`, and then parse it using a `NSXmlParser`, then you can display your information on your `UITableView`. Hope that helps.

Here is a nice tutorial: [IPhone RSS Reader Tutorial](http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader)